# How to get longitude and latitude of a city/country inputted through an input box?

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps

I have this code,

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myIP(){
$("#btn").click(function(){
            var geocoder =  new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': '#city'}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            alert("location : " + results[0].geometry.location.lat() + " " +results[0].geometry.location.lng()); 
          } else {
            alert("Something got wrong " + status);
          }
        });
});
}
 </script>
</head>
<body onload="myIP()">
<input type="text" id= "city">
<input id="btn" type="button" value="get Lat&Long" />
</body>
</html>
```

This will give me latitude and longitude of the inputted city in small dialog box. But I need this in the same page or parent page. Please help me

Comment: Is this your own code? In which case, what have you attempted?

Comment: not my code. I tried to input it through php input form in vain.

Comment: When I attempt to use this, I get the same coordinates no matter what I put in.

Comment: yes that is correct, so can anyone help me.

Comment: geocoder.geocode( { 'address': '#city'} . You are putting #city where you should put the input which is $('#city').val()

Comment: It's not working alkis

Comment: @phpbeg the suggestion @alkis mentioned did the trick when I tried it. The first parameter in `geocoder.geocode()` should be `{ 'address': $('#city').val()}`

Comment: can you help me with a complete code, because when i tried it was not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myIP(){
$("#btn").click(function(){

            var geocoder =  new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': $('#city').val()}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            $('.push-down').text("location : " + results[0].geometry.location.lat() + " " +results[0].geometry.location.lng()); 
          } else {
            $('.push-down').text("Something got wrong " + status);
          }
        });
});
}
 </script>
  <style>
    .push-down {margin-top: 25px;}</style>
</head>
<body onload="myIP()">
<input type="text" id= "city">
<input id="btn" type="button" value="get Lat&Long" />
  <div class="push-down"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But that code is still not working for me. Is there anything I need to add from my end.

Comment: What do you mean "is not working"? Are there any errors? What does the console of your browser say?

Comment: I am very sorry that was a mistake from my end. It is working perfectly. But can you help me with getting the result in a page rather than in dialogue popup box.

Comment: I updated the code to show the message a little below the input. You saild "a page" so I chose the same page. Please don't forget to accept the answer if this solves your problem.

Comment: Sure I will accept it, thanks a lot alkis, it's working perfectly.

Comment: Thanks so much. It was very handy. I created a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Bl_praveen2004/eg52f49h/

Comment: Could the API have changed requirements? This is no longer working for me locally nor on the jsfiddle: 'REQUEST_DENIED` error.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + Loc + '&sensor=false', null, function (data) {
                var p = data.results[0].geometry.location
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);                    
            });
```